# Intall magento extensions popup not working

Tags: magento

i intalled toogas featured popup free not working in magento
in admin panel shows CMS → Featured Popup free
and in past

```
<reference name="after_body_start">
<block type="featuredpopup/featuredpopup" name="toogasfeaturedpopup"  as="toogasfeaturedpopup"   template="toogas_featuredpopup/featuredpopup.phtml" />
</reference>
```

in cms page

i load home page nothing popup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe the javascript popup library conflict with Magento javascript library (Magento use prototype)...
if the popup js lib use jQuery..add script below, after jquery initialized

```
jQuery.noConflict();
```